# How to customize ActionBarSherlock tabs and tab bar

Tags: android, android-tabs

I want to customize ActionBarSherlock tabs and tab bar.It is like this. [image]

I want make it like this[image]

Comment: customizing it this way, even though it's possible, is not intuitive at all and doesn't look like an android app (looks more like IOS) . please consider using a different design. see here: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html .

Comment: I think you should play with ABS theme and drawable. By this you can customize ABS as you want.

Comment: @Vipul Could you please provide codes for it's implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom view to display the tabs. You could try a [3-arg LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) constructor (added in API 11). By specifying a default style in an XML file, the library tends to leverage the system layout inflator. So, you can also do a similar work around

```
<LinearLayout style="?attr/actionBarTabStyle" />
```

And then add the below code

```
LineraLayout tabView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_tab, null);
//set your layout params and setCustomView
```

Comment: I am using left/right swapping as well as tabs swapping. Then is your code will work in this situation ?

Comment: Yes, you can define a seperate layout file for each tab you have in your actionBar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is two links which will help you to customize ABS.

[Customize ActionBar TabBar (ActionBarSherlock)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957892/customize-actionbar-tabbar-actionbarsherlock)

**And**

[How to customize ActionBar in Android (ActionbarSherlock)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781853/how-to-customize-actionbar-in-android-actionbarsherlock)

basically you need to make changes in ABS themes and have to play with its drawable.